# I need to create a trigger which includes three databases

Tags: mysql, triggers

In Mysql, for a particular client, I need to create a trigger which includes three databases and i may have different clients. The table structure for each client will be same. I need database name in trigger need to be changed dynamically so that i can use single trigger to perform an action at same time. Is it possible?

I have tried dynamic sql in trigger but we can not use the same in trigger and stored function.

Please help.

Comment: I hope my question is clear now?3

Comment: Take this example: Suppose i have one client A for which i need to setup 3 databases a1, a2, a3. Database a1 contains t1, t2, t3 tables, Database a2 contains t4,t5, t6 tables and database t3 contains t7, t8, t9 tables. For this setup i can use one trigger say "triggs_1". What if i have more than clients with same table structure and i want trigger "triggs_1" needs to be used for every client. Is it possible? I hope my question is clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are designed database specific and are to handle `DML` operations within a single database.
Due to the reason, you can't have *global* triggers to fire across databases commonly. You have to write triggers separately for each of the database.

The only operations in which you can *refer* multiple databases are

- a `select` statement, like `select db1.tbl1.col2 ...`
- any statement that uses data from cross databases for data
  comparison. Like `where db2.tbl2.col3 = db1.tbl1....`

Comment: you can refer multiple database in UPDATE statement too while creating trigger.

Comment: Well, reference is acceptable as long as the operation won't affect the data in other databases.

Comment: I am doing the same and it is allowing me to do so.